# How would I create a site like the following one in Wordpress? My mind is being melted by this for some ridiculous reason

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

http://www.renegrafisch.nl

I want to take the [Responsive theme](http://themeid.com/responsive-theme/) and create a website out of it. However, from a fresh install, I have no idea how to take it from what seems like predominantly a blogging site with sidebars, to a fully robust business website.

Are there any tutorials out there to show how to transform a theme such as that into a robust, fully functioning business website?

All I end up with is this stuff about creating a template, but it still looks like it's creating a blog post.

I want separate sections on the website, which in normal web dev would be divs and divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn more about responsive design, I would check out the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) library, as it has that functionality as well as a whole bunch of other things that will help speed up your development process.

As for actually implementing this as a wordpress theme, I would read their [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), last time I did this (about 4 years ago), it wasn't too bad.